# How can we handle advertisement which could be appeared randomly in appium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

Could anyone please suggest how can we handle such advertisement which could be appeared randomly.

Advertisements would display around 10-20 seconds on the screen. It    can come at any situation for example : when user lands on any screen    then it may come or when user idle on the screen for some time then    it may come. **We can't predict when advertisement may come.**

**I am using java with appium.**

**Please suggest,Is there any way, we keep monitoring that Advertisement appears or not. If Advertisement appears just close the Advertisement if not then keep execute the steps of scripts.**

Please see the below screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASIZK.png)

Comment: You can find the element of the close tag. And put if condition or try/catch saying if that element is visible then close it or ignore it, Make a locator which remains constant for that close button.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi Kishan,If every action such as click etc, I apply to find the close button element then I worried it would increase test execution time. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: See once the page is loaded for advertisement you cannot do anything, So put it in try and catch and see wherever this adds are coming or enhance to pro version :-).
See this . It may help you.
https://community.perfectomobile.com/series/25427/posts/1129694